# Sum of binomial coefficients, with alternate signs, congruent two or zero modulo four

Tags: summation, proof-writing, binomial-coefficients

I've come across the following formula:

$$
S(n) \;:=
\sum
  _{
    \begin{array}{c}
       k=0 \\ 
       k \equiv_4 0,\; 2
    \end{array}
   }
  ^{
     n
   }
2 \cdot 
\binom{n}{k}\cdot 
(-1)^{k \over 2} $$

where the summation run over the values of $k$ in $[0, n]$ that are congruent modulo 4 to 0 or 2.

Can this be simplified?

---

I've *numerically* verified that the sum takes the following values:
$$
S(n) =
\begin{cases}
(-1)^{n \over 4} \cdot 2^{{n\over 2} + 1},  & \text{if $n \equiv_4 0 $} \\
S(n-1) ,  & \text{if $n \equiv_4 1 $} \\
0,  & \text{if $n \equiv_4 2 $} \\
(-1)^{n +1 \over 4} \cdot 2^{n+1\over2},  & \text{if $n \equiv_4 3 $} \\
\end{cases}
$$

but except for the case $n \equiv_4 2 $ I can see why this is the case.

Particularly interesting, to me, are the fact that this sum is either 0 or a power of two and the case $n \equiv_4 1 $ where the two partial sums of the binomial coefficients in adjacent rows total the same (e.g. $ 2 \cdot 1 - 2 \cdot 6 + 2 \cdot 1 = 2 \cdot 1 - 2 \cdot 10 + 2 \cdot 5$ for the 5th and 6th row of the Pascal's triangle).

Comment: Two possible simplifications. The sum is over all even $k$; no need to think mod $4$ about the index. You can factor $2$ from the sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$S(n)=2\sum_{k\equiv_40,2}^n(-1)^{k/2}\binom nk=2\Big(\binom n0-\binom n2+\binom n4...\Big)$$

Consider $(1+x)^n=\binom n0+\binom n1x+\binom n2x^2+...+\binom nnx^n$.

Substitute $x=i$ to get$$(1+i)^n=\binom n0+\binom n1i-\binom n2-\binom n3i+\binom n4...$$

This gives$$\mathfrak R((1+i)^n)=\frac{S(n)}2\\\therefore S(n)=2\mathfrak R(2^{n/2}e^{in\pi/4})=2^{n/2+1}\cos(n\pi/4)$$